# Optics that translates object to image by a constant amount

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, applied-physics, imaging

For some application I was interested in an optics s.t. for any incoming ray the outcoming ray is parallel to the incoming ray and shifted by a distance $d$ (independent of the incoming ray) along the optical axis. The system should be shorter than $d$ for the application.

[image: illustration of the desired system]

Such a system would image any point to a point shifted by $d$ along the optical axis.

I am interested if there is a name for such an optical system, if it is being used somewhere how it would look like and where it is available.

I know that a grin lens with pitch 1.0 would have this property but this system would be as long as $d$ which makes it infeasible for my application.

I can theoretically construct such a system using multiple thin lenses, either four lenses with focal length f=d/8 or three lenses with focal lengths f, f/2, f in this order. Two consecutive lenses are placed 2f apart from each other in both cases (see below). However I don't know if one can make a good real design with small aberration etc. out of this.

[image: Three lens system]
[image: Four lens system]

Comment: If you really just want a shift, why not use something similar to periscope?

Comment: I want the optics and the translation along one line. Furthermore the optics should be shorter than the translation.

Comment: Doesn't a rectangular glass block do this automatically? If I understand correctly in your diagram the angle of transmission is equal to the angle of incidence. So any rectangular material with a refractive index will do this.

Comment: the incoming and outgoing rays are parallel if we use a glass block but the translation depends on the direction of the incoming ray. A glass block does no imaging.

Comment: Try using two identical lenses separated by 4f.

Comment: Its not possible with two lenses since if a ray not on the optical axis goes throgh the center of the first lens it does not get refracted by the first lens but by the second, so the incoming ray can not be parallel to the outgoing ray.